# Does moving photos to multiple USB drives make the photos decrease in quality?

Tags: photos

Does moving photos over and over again make the photos decrease in quality? In either device?

Comment: No! Why would you even think that?

Comment: the question would be if you're just duplicating files, or if you're "saving as" a different size or resolution..  

IF just duplicating the file, no there is NO degredation (hence the term "digital copy")... 

If you're opening and doing a "Save As", you can theoretically save a photo at the same or a lower resolution, resulting in lower quality (and smaller size)..

Comment: Dragging the folder into the USB.

Answer (score 1):

No, just copying the file can't degrade the quality. You can copy ad infinitum, and you should always end up with an identical digital replica.

Comment: If you were to open the file, then "Save As", then open that, and "Save As", and so on, that would degrade the image (depending on file format), but copying the file itself makes an exact duplicate of its binary representation on the disk.